# mysql table partition issue

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am trying to understand mysql table partitioning, below are details and example which i tried.

mysql version - 8.0.27

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
   id INT NOT NULL,
   fname VARCHAR(30),
   lname VARCHAR(30),
   hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
   separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
   job_code INT,
   store_id INT
)
ENGINE=INNODB
PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(separated))(
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN(1991),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN(1996),
   PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN(2001),
   PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Sample insert statement.

```
insert into employees values (1,'ron', 'nath', '2019-10-10', '2021-10-12',123,123);
insert into employees values (2,'ram', 'nath', '1991-10-10', '1999-10-12',123,123);
```

Verified data loaded in partition.

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='employees';
```

This shows data in two partition p2 and p3. But when i run below select statement and do explain, i see all the partition being referred.

```
EXPLAIN select * from employees where year(separated)='1999';
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see in both screen shots, All partitions are referred, not sure why? I am expected only specific partition to be referred when where clause filter applied to fetch data from specific partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in WHERE does not allow to use partition pruning. The fact that the expression in WHERE matches the partitioning expression is not taken into account.

Use

```sql
select * from employees where separated BETWEEN '1999-01-01' AND '1999-12-31';
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9463013d90bfce805b86ed1eb601836c)

---

### UPDATE

You may create generated column which stores extracted year value and partition by it.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea6d5f06172aba815a335a3deee873aa)

Comment: @Raj Answer updated. Maybe this will be useful for you. Generated column does not occupy place in the table's body due to it is virtual. But its usage simplifies the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
where year(separated)='1999';
```

`separated` is hidden in a function call, hence not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .  Akina elaborates on it.

I suggest

```
WHERE separated >= '1999-01-01'
  AND separated  < '1999-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

But...  The non-partitioned equivalent table will let that Select run just as fast.  (It would need `INDEX(separated)`.)  So, I ask what are you hoping to gain by Partitioning?

A common reason for Partitioning a time series is to make the deletion of 'old' data faster.  This can be done via `DROP PARTITION`.  [*details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

**Data Warehousing**

For a rapidly growing "Fact" table, Partition *only* as a way of deleting "old" rows.  `DROP PARTITION` is immensely faster and less invasive than `DELETE`.  `SELECT` from the Fact table *only* for individual rows.  There should be very few indexes on the Fact table.  [*DW blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse)

Build and maintain a "Summary Table" for most reports, graphs, etc.  This would typically be a table with a 'date' and one or more dimensions, plus counts and subtotals for each date.  *This* gives you the speed you desire.  [*Summary blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

If you are pushing the limits of Insert speed, consider batching, ping-ponging, etc.  [*Ingestion blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)

Comment: I have fact table in mysql which has millions of records and its getting bigger with every day. I am looking to partition this table to make query works better and have better control over data. In my case, most of the time query will access data based on date. Let me know if you see better solution for such use case.

Comment: @Raj - Use a Summary table -- see my added text.

Comment: Thanks, but on top of fact i have created summary table. So far it is working fine but was looking to even partition the summary table because of data size.

Comment: @Raj - Partitioning the summary table (by dates) is OK, but unusual.  Will the Summary table grow to more than a million rows?  Will you purge 'old' data from it?  (Those are two simple criteria for judging whether to Partition a time-series table.  It can apply to your Summary table.)  Perhaps you would like to start a new Question and discuss it with details.